# Convert String Value to Date/Datetime in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I was loading DB2 table into mysql and I was facing issue while loading data with Date format.

I converted those columns into VARCHAR(26) format and loaded the data successfully.

Now I want to convert **2003-01-13-16.50.32.000000** into Date format.

I introduced another column with Date datatype and tried to update it using origional (String) column.

```
update po_datamart
    set POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP=DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(POH_APPROVED_DATE,'%Y-%c-%d-%H.%i.%s'), '%Y-%c-%d%H:%m:%s');
```

I am getting following error "Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2003-01-13-16.50.32.000000'".

Would appreciate if anyone can help me with this VARCHAR to DATE conversion.

Comment: Please avoid blasting every answer with the same verbose comment.  Instead, you could update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `STR_TO_DATE` with an appropriate format mask:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2003-01-13-16.50.32.000000', '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f')
```

If you wanted to update:

```
UPDATE po_datamart
SET POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP = STR_TO_DATE(POH_APPROVED_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f')
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Hello Tim. Thanks for your reply. When I fire your select query, I get response as NULL value. When I run your update query, I get "Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '2003-01-13-16.50.32.000000' for function str_to_date"

Comment: @user2663104 Sorry I have updated and it works now.  I was using `%h` for 12 hour time instead of `%H` for 24 hour time.

Comment: UPDATE po_datamart SET POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP = STR_TO_DATE(POH_APPROVED_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f') - This query worked but again ended with response - "Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '+0.00000000000000E+000' for function str_to_date"

Comment: What actual string data are you feeding in?  It looks like you are using a non standard format.

Comment: I used .del file, It is a dump file of the old Data warehouse table which was there in DB2. I used LOAD INLINE functionality to upload the data in the table(MySQL).

Comment: This wasn't my question.  I think the strings you are passing cannot all be formatted correctly into dates.  Check you source data please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need and space, try with:

```
set POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP=DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(POH_APPROVED_DATE,'%Y-%c-%d-%H.%i.%s'), '%Y-%c-%d %H:%m:%s');
```

I change the last string `'%Y-%c-%d%H:%m:%s'` to `'%Y-%c-%d %H:%m:%s'`.

**Update** for a `date` column:

```
set POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP=DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(POH_APPROVED_DATE,'%Y-%c-%d-%H.%i.%s'), '%Y-%c-%d');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got  the response as "Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect date time value: '2003-01-13-16.50.32.000000'"

Comment: I try the code and seems to work correctly; what data type have `POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP` (date, datetime, other?). If the column is `date` type then the data is truncated, you use `2003-01-13 16:50:32` with a column that only admits `2003-01-13`. I edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I am using Date. Should I use datetime?

Comment: Read my answer, the first code if for datetime column, but I made an update for date column. Use as you wish.

Comment: UPDATE po_datamart
SET POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP = STR_TO_DATE(POH_APPROVED_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f') - This query worked but again ended with response - "Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '+0.00000000000000E+000' for function str_to_date"

Comment: Check the values of `POH_APPROVED_DATE`, maybe some in your table can't be converted to datetime because don't have the format `%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f`.

Comment: Thanks. I think there is issue in source data. I am using this data with Tableau. I will try to figure out this issue in Tableau.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update po_datamart set POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP = str_to_date(POH_APPROVED_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect date time value: '2003-01-13-16.50.32.000000'
Got above error.

Comment: Is `POH_APPROVED_DATE`'s type is varchar or date?

Comment: POH_APPROVED_DATE's type is varchar

Comment: @user2663104 Updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: UPDATE po_datamart
SET POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP = STR_TO_DATE(POH_APPROVED_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f') - This query worked but again ended with response - "Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '+0.00000000000000E+000' for function str_to_date"

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE      po_datamart
    SET     POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP = str_to_date(POH_APPROVED_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f');
```

Comment: UPDATE po_datamart
SET POH_APPROVED_DATE_TEMP = STR_TO_DATE(POH_APPROVED_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f') - This query worked but again ended with response - "Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '+0.00000000000000E+000' for function str_to_date"

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?